# How compute combinatorial expression

Tags: co.combinatorics

How compute 
   $\sum_{j=1}^k  \binom{x}{j}\binom{k-1}{j-1}\alpha^j, \quad x, \alpha\in\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 3):

The sum equals $x \, _2F_1(1-k,1-x;2;a).$ For more on this, check out Abramowitz and Stegun, or some such.